# Flask & Bootstrap Multiple collapsibles, but they each only open the first

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask

I have an HTML page displaying a database populated by emails.  I have them displayed in a collapsible, and for each post the timestamp of it is what toggles it and the innards are the email itself.   The HTML page is structured like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for email in emails %}
<div><button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">{{ email.timestamp }}</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
{{ email.body }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

relevant portion of `views.py`

```
@app.route('/cruz')
def cruz():
    u = Politician.query.get(1)
    emails = u.emails.all()
    return render_template('cruz.html',title='Ted Cruz',emails=emails)
```

which produces a webpage that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPNJF.jpg

The problem is that no matter which of those timestamps I click, only the first collapsible opens and closes.  I've tried a number of things to fix it, mostly messing around with the HTML page and the `for` blocks and where I place the `{{ email.body }}`, but nothing I do seems to work.  Can anyone see where this is going wrong?

Comment: You are generating `div` elements with the *same `id`* for each.

Comment: thanks so much @MartijnPieters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating the same `id` attribute for your `div` each time:

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
```

You almost certainly need to generate unique ids. You could generate unique ids by adding the loop index perhaps:

```
<div id="demo-{{loop.index}}" class="collapse">
```